# why I'm getting "fd must not be null" validation error on adding sticker pack to WhatsApp using contentProvider

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I'm developing an android application for adding custom stickers to WhatsApp.On adding sticker to WhatsApp a error dailog is shown with message "There is some issue with this sticker pack and it cannot be added to Whatsap". The error I get onActivitResult is "fd should not be invalid". I can't track down the reason for this error.

This is my json file which i create in my project:

```
[
   {
      "identifier":"2",
      "isWhitelisted":false,
      "licenseAgreementWebsite":"",
      "name":"Prank",
      "privacyPolicyWebsite":"",
      "publisher":"Bilal",
      "publisherEmail":"",
      "publisherWebsite":"",
      "stickers":[
         {
            "emojis":[
               
            ],
            "imageFileName":"0",
            "size":0,
            "uri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_0.webp"
         },
         {
            "emojis":[
               
            ],
            "imageFileName":"1",
            "size":0,
            "uri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_1.webp"
         },
         {
            "emojis":[
               
            ],
            "imageFileName":"2",
            "size":0,
            "uri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_2.webp"
         },
         {
            "emojis":[
               
            ],
            "imageFileName":"3",
            "size":0,
            "uri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_3.webp"
         },
         {
            "emojis":[
               
            ],
            "imageFileName":"4",
            "size":0,
            "uri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_4.webp"
         }
      ],
      "stickersAddedIndex":5,
      "totalSize":0,
      "trayImageFile":"trayimage",
      "trayImageUri":"/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.firebase.stickersload/Prank/image_0.png"
   }
]
```

Here is my contentProvider Method "openAssetFile" in which this method is occurring.

```
 override fun openAssetFile(uri: Uri, mode: String): AssetFileDescriptor? {
        val matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri)
        Log.d("de_sticker", uri.toString() + " facffffff")
        Log.w("de_sticker", uri.path + " uri path")
        val pathSegments = uri.pathSegments
        val csp: StickerPack? = StickerBook.getStickerPackByIdWithContext(
            pathSegments[pathSegments.size - 2],
            context
        )
        Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: id: ${pathSegments.size-2}")

        if (csp != null) {
            val filename = pathSegments[pathSegments.size - 1]
            Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: path segments file name: ${filename}")
            var pfd: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null

            try {
                if (filename == "trayimage" && csp.trayImageFile != null) {

                    pfd = Objects.requireNonNull(context)!!.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(
                        csp.trayImageUri!!, "r"
                    )
                    Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: pdf is:  ${pfd}")
                    Log.d(
                        "de_sticker",
                        java.lang.String.valueOf(csp.trayImageFile) + ""
                    )
                } else {
                    try {
                        pfd = Objects.requireNonNull(context)!!.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(
                            csp.getStickerById(Integer.valueOf(filename))!!.uri!!, "r"
                        )
                        Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: else condition $pfd")
                        Log.w(
                            "ASSETFILE ACTUAL URI", java.lang.String.valueOf(
                                csp.getStickerById(
                                    Integer.valueOf(filename)
                                )!!.uri
                            ) + ""
                        )
                    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                        Log.d(
                            "de_sticker",
                            "WhatsApp tried to access a non existent sticker, id: $filename"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            Log.d("de_sticker", "openAssetFile: pfd is $pfd")
            return AssetFileDescriptor(pfd, 0, AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH)
        }
        return getImageAsset(uri)
        /*if (matchCode == STICKERS_ASSET_CODE || matchCode == STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE) {
            return getImageAsset(uri);
        }
        return null;*/
    }
```

Is there something i am missing here? Can somebody please help me out with this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Note:** all the given uris(images) are placed in my mobile device and i allow all required permissions as well